# calling an available package(APIs) from another package

Tags: ros, package, youbot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello All,

I am working on kuka youbot. I have to use API functions for operating the base of youbot. To do this, I need to create a user application based on the ROS package which calls the youbot API functions from the Library/package of those APIs.
Dose anyone knows how do I do this procedure? Any ideas or tutorial links would be helpful.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/198182/calling-an-available-package(apis)-from-another-package/) by [A.M Dynamics](https://answers.ros.org/users/20607/a.m-dynamics/) on ROS Answers with karma: 93 on 2014-11-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This may help:

http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/catkin/html/howto/format2/system_library_dependencies.html

As may this:

http://answers.ros.org/question/118231/how-to-add-non-cmake-based-libraries-to-a-catkin-build/

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2014-11-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [A.M Dynamics](https://answers.ros.org/users/20607/a.m-dynamics/) on 2014-12-26**:
@Tom Moore. Thanks for help. My problem was solved.